# Check for duplicates within multi-di assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array like the one below, I need to check for duplicates within the multi-dimensional associative array. I don't think that I really need to say much more, I've already tried `array_unique` and it happens to think things are duplicates when they clearly aren't.

I'm looking to change this:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["itself"]=>
    string(31) "New York"
    ["status"]=>
    string(18) "great"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["itself"]=>
    string(36) "New York"
    ["status"]=>
    string(22) "great"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["itself"]=>
    string(29) "New York"
    ["status"]=>
    string(18) "great"
  }
}
```

In to this:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["itself"]=>
    string(31) "New York"
    ["status"]=>
    string(18) "great"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an actual output, because the string-lengths don't match... Maybe some hidden data (html-tags, non-printable characters, etc.)?

If not: array_unique wants a string representation:

```
 $result = array_intersect_key(
      $input,
      array_unique(array_map('serialize',$input)));
```

Comment: The string length was a typo, I changed the original values. This works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(YOUR ARRAY);

foreach ($array as $key1 => $value1){
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $value2){
        if($array[$key1] == $array[$key2] && $key1 != $key2){
            unset($array[$key1]);
        }
    }
}
```